# How to test getDerivedStateFromProps with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have this simple code that is using the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: Props, prevState: State) {
  if (nextProps.value !== prevState.value) {
    console.log('hello');
    return {
      value: nextProps.value
    };
  }

  return null;
}
```

And this is the test:

```
it('should call getDerivedStateFromProps', () => {
  const instance = shallow(mockComponent());

  instance.setProps({ value: 'test2' });

  expect(instance.state.value).toEqual('test2');
});
```

But I have this error but I know that is calling because of the console.log().

```
Expected value to equal:
  "test2"
Received:
  undefined
```

How do I test properly `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

I'm using:

```
react: 16.4
react-Dom: 16.4
enzyme-adapter-react-16: 1.1.1
react-test-renderer: 16.4.1
```

Comment: Looks like you may have to reinstall the enzyme adapter:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1600

Comment: It didn't work :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a static function with no dependency. I think you can test it in isolation like every other function:

```
const givenProps = {...};
const givenState = {...};
const result = MyComponent.getDerivedStateFromProps(givenProps, givenState);

expect(result).toEqual({
  ...
})
```

I think it is a valid approach because of [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) should not contain any side-effects and be pure - which means - given the same input it will produce the same output. And because the instance of a component has no relevance here creating one would test nothing but react internals.

This would be also similar to how you would test a redux reducer.

Comment: But can I do that with enzyme for example? I know that I can do that for example: ```instance.componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps);```

Comment: That solution works. If you know how to do it with enzyme, tell me :)

Comment: @AlbertOlivé There's a difference between an instance method and static method. You can only call instance method once you created an object (a component), but you call a static method by referencing a constructor. So I think `instance.contructor.getDerivedStateFromProps ` would probably work, however, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience you should not call directly the "getDerivedStateFromProps" function to test it. It's part of the component's lifecycle, therefore all you need to do is to:

1. Initiate the component with a value in state.
2. Update props with new value.
3. check the state (since it will be updated because the "getDerivedStateFromProps" function will be automatically called.

For example:

```
describe('getDerivedStateFromProps', () => {
        it('new value arrived from props and state is updated', () => {
            const newValue = 'NewVal';
            const wrapper = createAndMountComponent(params); // here initiate your component wrapper
            const instance = wrapper.instance();

            wrapper.setProps({ value: newValue });  // update props

            const { value, valueFromProps } = instance.state; // check if the value in state was updated
            expect(value).toEqual(newValue);
            expect(valueFromProps).toEqual(newValue);
        });
});
```

This is enough to test the "getDerivedStateFromProps" function. Of course you should not forget to update the value inside the "getDerivedStateFromProps" function:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const { value } = props;
    const { valueFromProps } = state;

    if (value !== valueFromProps) {
        return {
            value,
            valueFromProps: value
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the static getDerivedStateFromProps we can test with the below code

```
let wrapper = shallow(      
        <Component {...props} />      
      );
const givenProps = {...};
const givenState = {...};
const result = wrapper.instance().constructor.getDerivedStateFromProps(givenProps , givenState );
expect(result).toEqual({
  ...
})
```

Answer (score -2):

wrapper = shallow()
wrapper.instance.getDerivedStateFromProps