# How to test getDerivedStateFromProps with jest

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I have looked at [How to test getDerivedStateFromProps with Jest and Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855594/how-to-test-getderivedstatefromprops-with-jest-and-enzyme) but it is not working for me. here is my test

```
it('should be red processing only, routing, security grey while bg tasks are running', () => {
        component = mount(
            <ProcessingStatus store={store}/>
        );
        const instance = component.instance();
        //console.log(instance)
        component.setProps({ processing_status: {
                header:{
                    error: true,
                    message: 'This comms matrix is currently processing flows',
                    statusCode: 200
                },
                body: {}
            } });

        console.log(component.state())
console.log(component.props())
        expect(component.find(TrafficLight).length).toEqual(3);
        expect(component.find(TrafficLight).at(0).props().RedOn).toEqual(true);
        expect(component.find(TrafficLight).at(0).props().AmberOn).toEqual(false);
        expect(component.find(TrafficLight).at(0).props().GreenOn).toEqual(false);
    });
```

`component.state()` or `instance.state` is always empty `{}`.

This is the contents of `component.props()`

```
{ store:
       { getState: [Function: getState],
         getActions: [Function: getActions],
         dispatch:
          { [Function: mockConstructor]
            _isMockFunction: true,
            getMockImplementation: [Function],
            mock: [Getter/Setter],
            mockClear: [Function],
            mockReset: [Function],
            mockRestore: [Function],
            mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
            mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
            mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
            mockReturnValue: [Function],
            mockResolvedValue: [Function],
            mockRejectedValue: [Function],
            mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
            mockImplementation: [Function],
            mockReturnThis: [Function],
            mockName: [Function],
            getMockName: [Function] },
         clearActions: [Function: clearActions],
         subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
         replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer] },
      processing_status:
       { header:
          { error: true,
            message: 'This comms matrix is currently processing flows',
            statusCode: 200 },
         body: {} } }
```

I need this to be triggered as depending on my props values the state changes and renders other conditions.

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856338/3731501 in dupe question should work. getDerivedStateFromProps is pure function and can be tested as such. Your test doesn't do what's suggested there.

Comment: can you tell me what i am doing wrong. because i mounted the component. create instance set props on wrapper and checked instance state which is empty

Comment: I can't say, I'd expect it to work, as with any newer React API, there were problems with getDerivedStateFromProps but they were mostly fixed https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues?q=is%3Aissue+getDerivedStateFromProps . You probably use some obsolete package version. Any way, if you want to investigate this further, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Since Enzyme isn't a real renderer, you shouldn't expect it to always behave like real renderer. In case it doesn't for some reason, getDerivedStateFromProps can be tested like shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a connected component it needs to be retrieved differently.

```
component = mount(
            <ProcessingStatus store={store}/>
        );
        const instance = component.find('ProcessingStatus').instance();
        component.setProps({ processing_status: {
                header:{
                    error: true,
                    message: 'This comms matrix is currently processing flows',
                    statusCode: 200
                },
                body: {}
            } });

        console.log(instance.state);
```

Provided me with

```
 console.log tests/jest/components/common/ProcessingStatus/index.test.js:122
    { nextStep: 'This comms matrix is currently processing flows' }
```

What is not clear in previous answers is if there are `connected` or not and if `shallow` or `mount` is being used